# How do I search for a word in the entire XML using Regex?

Tags: c#, xml, regex, silverlight

In my XML I want to search for Text=" if it is not present then I want to do this

```
XMLString = Regex.Replace(XMLString,@"(?<=<Run[^<]*)>", " Text=\"",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Now whats the regex to find Text=" in the entire XML?

Comment: You should use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(XMLString," Text=\"")==false)
           XMLString = Regex.Replace(XMLString,@"(?<=<Run[^<]*)>", " Text=\"",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I hope there are no text nodes that contain the literal Text="